# Can't Login to Website Using Python Session Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-3.4

I'm new to web scraping, and I'm attempting to log in to imagingrewardsprogram.com using requests.Session(). I've been able to successfully log in to other websites, and I'm stumped why I haven't been able to log into this one.

When I login to the site in Google Chrome and view the form data in developer tools, I'm able to see that the form data I'm passing in to my code is identical to the form data I pass in to the web browser ("user" and "password"). I'm sure there's something else I should be passing in that I'm missing, but I'm not sure what it is.

Here is my code:

```
loginURL = 'https://imagingrewardsprogram.com'
requestURL = ''https://imagingrewardsprogram.com/merlin/pnaimaging?command=get&style=home'

payload = { 
    'user': myusername,
    'password': mypassword,
    'command':'get',
    'style':'home'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(loginURL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(requestURL)
    print(r.text)
```

The output I get is a page that says, "Either your session has expired or an error occurred while obtaining your account information."

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the `session.auth` as show in the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)?

Comment: You are probably missing something needed in the payload. press ctrl+shift+I and then login and look at the Form Data. If you are having problems you can use selenium.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. I haven't had any luck yet. I'm passing in all the correct form information. I'll check out selenium.

Comment: I was able to access the page. I found that if I included all the POST information in the URL (including my login information), I could access any page without logging in through the login page. (ie: imagingrewardsprogram.com/merlin/pnaimaging?command=get&style=home&user=myusername&password=mypassword). Simply requesting that URL in the code works too. 

I'm confused why it works but happy I can get in. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one reason can be website you are trying to access uses better security that does not allow automatic process to login.

So, thats why you are unable to create a session using a script.
Security like captcha and re- captcha are used to prevent automatic login.

Comment: There is no captcha or other intermediary steps after submitting the form for the user to perform when logging in. My understanding of Session objects is that they capture cookies and maintain those cookies for future requests. I was wondering if there's something else I need to pass in like a special header from my visit to the login page when I make the request.